# View is taking full screen height

Tags: android, view

I have the following code in the android XML layout.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginSmall"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/item_margin">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/jobFieldList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin"
            app:fieldEditable="@{true}"
            app:fieldsMap="@{viewModel.job.jobFields}"
            app:jobFields="@{jobFields}" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/jobFieldsNoAccess"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.attributes.referral.usersReferred >= 2 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}" />

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The view with id **jobFieldsNoAccess** is visible only based on a certain condition.
The RecyclerView **jobFieldList** can have one or more items.

*I want the view must take the whole height equal to the height of the recycler view, that's why it is match_parent. But...*

**The issue is:**

Even the RecyclerView **jobFieldList** has one item which is taking a small amount of height. But the view **jobFieldsNoAccess**, if visible, takes the whole screen height.

[image]

The issue is not on all devices. Only on some devices with Android 10 has that issue.

Why the view **jobFieldsNoAccess** is taking the whole height? How can I fix that?

Comment: I have a better understanding of what your view layout is now. I also need to see the layout containing this `CardView`. Also, what is `jobFieldsNoAccess` supposed to render? It is blank in your example, correct?

Comment: `jobFieldsNoAccess` is just the overlay to prevent using the recycler view items. Yes, it is just blank with a white background and 0.75 alpha.

Comment: The problem is as I said in my answer. `match_parent` fills the `FrameLayout`. I'm not sure how to make it the same size and position as the `RecyclerView`. Maybe try a `ConstraintLayout` instead of `FrameLayout`. Also, have you considered just disabling the elements in the RecyclerView instead of a transparent overlay?

Comment: The recycler view may have a lot of elements like more than 50. The above was working fine but some users just reported this issue. They have the Android 10. I tested it on Android 10 and it is working fine on my side. I'm not able to produce the issue. So I posted the question here to know what is wrong in the code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The issue is resolved by using the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer below with your solution

Comment: already posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by using the `RelativeLayout` instead of `FrameLayout`.
Aligned the top and bottom of `View: jobFieldsNoAccess` with `RecyclerView: jobFieldList`

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginSmall"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/item_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/jobFieldList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin"
            app:fieldEditable="@{true}"
            app:fieldsMap="@{viewModel.job.jobFields}"
            app:jobFields="@{jobFields}" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/jobFieldsNoAccess"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/jobFieldList"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/jobFieldList"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.attributes.referral.usersReferred >= 2 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why the view jobFieldsNoAccess is taking the whole height?

Because you tell it to with `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

> How can I fix that?

By secifying a explicit height or use `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.

Comment: I want the view must take the whole height equal to the height of the recycler view. that's why it is match_parent.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal The `FrameView` is the parent, not the `RecyclerView`, so `match_parent` fills the rest of the `FrameView`.

Comment: `FrameView` is the parent but its height depends on the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal Also, why do you have a RecyclerView inside a CardLayout? Do you expect to have a list of items in the RecyclerView? From your screenshot it is unclear what elements are what.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal It will help if you also provide a drawing to show what you want instead. I think you don't need the RecyclerView at all, unless you need the same view elements repeated over and over again.